# Get userID of current windows user in my website via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, active-directory, windows-authentication, smartcard

I have a feature in my upcoming web project where I will have to get the UserID/Email ID of the user currently logged in to the machine/PC. Target OS is Windows 10 and logins to the machines are done via Smart Card only. User Data is stored inside MS-AD.

This UserID will be used passed further for Authorization and load the app in browser. The target browser is IE and Chrome.

Is there a way i can fetch the EmailID/UserID of the User logged in via Smart Card to system in Javascript?

ADDITIONAL INFO: The website is setup in private environment. There is no public URL to access the webapp from outside Intranet. The client and backend code is hosted inside VM in Cloud. In nutshell, the is all sitting in private environment in Azure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not with JavaScript. JavaScript is run inside the browser container, and more specifically run inside your current webview. Letting JavaScript get access to settings and data on the local machine be a nightmare if phishing, malware and virus sites.

If you know which computers will run your website you could create an application with a server that's running idle on the machine, much like how Spotify's client is doing (the windows client can take commands from the webpage).

The application/server could then try to get the EmailID/UserID from the computer, and then having the server running on some specific port, your JavaScript could then use AJAX-requests to communicate with the local machine from the browser.

Comment: I have added some data on the infrastructure we are using. Will this help?

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't matter if the website is only accessible on an intranet, it's not the server location that's the matter, it's a browser security issue. The only way is if there's support from the client, in which I described one way in my answer. You can [search for similar issues](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/272019/communicating-between-browser-and-a-native-application-securely) on SE, this isn't a unique problem.

Answer (score 1):

I could get the Windows Logged in user using the ActiveX script in IE.

```
var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
alert(WinNetwork.UserName)
```

Will this be a good approach to solve this issue?

Comment: If you consider only using IE, yes. But now reached the end of it's life, so no user will use it anymore.